# How to extract a word and its next 2 digit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hRKD.png)

I want to extract word id and nid and its next 2 digit from log column using python. The output should be like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbLr0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.extract` we can try:

```py
df["log"] = df["log"].str.extract(r'\b(n?id \d+)')
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9XI3Zx/1).